# Can't repair broken link to image texture

Tags: image, path

I moved some files being used as image textures and Blender showed those objects in pink when I reopened the file. So, I fixed the path to one of the images being used for one texture, but the object stayed pink. So I eliminated all users for that image, that material, and that texture, closed the program, opened it again, and created the texture fresh. Now the object shows gray. In the Properties > Texture tab, it shows fine, in the Materials tab it shows fine, and when I load it in the Image Editor, it shows fine. But it isn't on the object.

I *could* try deleting the object and starting over. I'm asking before trying that though. I have copied the numerical values for its scale, rotation, and position so I could just type them in again, but I'm still a weensy bit nervous that will go wrong and I'll have to do the painstaking adjustments on it all over again. So, if there is a way to jog Blender's memory about where to get that file, I'd prefer to do that. Besides, I don't understand why this has happened.

I imported the image as a plane with that add-on. And the file contains a number of very large images - I am abusing Blender to splice together a set of photos of the Moon, as it is handling the job actually much better than GIMP or Krita on my Linux machine. At the moment it is handling 9 images that are 5000 px wide and 15000 to 25000 px long. Perhaps these things matter, I don't know. Probably not.

[image: screenshot of Blender Texture dialogue]

Comment: Gray normally means "no image texture or material assigned". You wrote in your question, that you deleted the material, so there's the problem with the gray plane. Also be aware that you might have created a new image by "fixing" the path. If you want to replace an image, click on the folder icon under "Image - Source".

Comment: @metaphor_set No, i rebuilt the material too, and assigned it to the object. I hadn't put that in the question, i've fixed that now.

Comment: How did you reassign the texture? Selecting it with the file selector under "Source" normally works fine for me.

Comment: @metaphor_set yes, that's what i did. I have now rebuilt them by re-importing the images as planes. I don't know what went wrong, but provisionally i am blaming it on the fact i didn't notice the UPS unit the computer is connected to was turned off. We get an awful lot of power fluctuations here. (Rural Mexico.)